# Gluten-free restaurants in Riga

Tags: restaurants, riga, dietary-restrictions

I will be travelling to Riga for a few days & being a coeliac, I would really appreciate any recommendations for gluten-free restaurants.

Answer (score 4):

You may not be aware of a website suitable for people with your condition, called [CeliacTravel](http://www.celiactravel.com/)?

On their site, for Riga, for example, [they make mention of](http://www.celiactravel.com/blog/gluten-free-restaurant-in-riga-latvia/) a restaurant called [Raw Garden](http://www.rawgarden.lv/?lang=en):

> "Now that I am in Latvia, I found a restaurant called [Raw Garden](http://www.rawgarden.lv/?lang=en)
>   . I've dined there, and its not fast by any
>   means, but its fresh, flavourful and gluten free"

In addition, you can show the following card to the chefs (or people at your hotel) to describe the problems you face and how you'd like your food prepared.  It's in Latvian:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Did find Raw Garden. Really looking for finer dining experiences where chef's are happy to make changes if needed.